# WaitForSeconds in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, frame-rate, ienumerator

I have an IENumerator in Unity wich activates a floor object every 0.70f-0.82f, so the gaps between the floor objects are randomly generated. The problem is, that when someone gets an FPS drop, the gaps are going to be huge and they player has no chance to reach the next floor. Can I make the "yield WaitForSeconds" fps-independent?
This is the code:

```
IEnumerator spawnFloors () {

    while (playerControll.isAlive) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < floors.Length; i++) {

                            spawnWait = Random.Range (0.70f, 0.82f);  // 0.65f, 0.85f; aktuell = 0.70f, 0.82f;
                            Vector2 spawnPosition = new Vector2 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
                            Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;
                            for (int a = 0; a < floors.Length; a++) {
                                    int randomFloor = Random.Range (0, 9);
                                    if (!floors [randomFloor].activeInHierarchy) {
                                            floors [randomFloor].SetActive (true);
                                            break;

                                    }
                            }
                            //Instantiate(floors[Random.Range (0, 3)], spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
                            yield return new WaitForSeconds (spawnWait);


                    }
            }

    }`
```

Comment: This is by definition fps-independent. The rest of the game seems not be. Are you using `Time.deltaTime` for player movement ?

Comment: Yes I am. Everything is working fine except of this problem. It happens hardly often, but I cant afford to let people experience this bug.

Comment: you can generate floor values in separate thread.

Comment: And how would I do that? Is there no way i can use this code with a little tweaking so it works in real seconds? And how would i achieve multi-threaded coding in unity? I'm developing for mobile btw.

Comment: You can use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch(); It will be more accurate as it will not depend on unity's internal clock but on the system. Here, you may find an example- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952773/display-an-object-for-a-few-milliseconds-in-unity3d

Comment: Allright, and how would I implement this in my code? I'm not that good at coding actually and I dont want to have more problems than I'm having now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using [`FixedUpdate()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) instead?

In case you are wondering [what's the difference](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/73713/update-vs-fixedupdate-in-unity), unity has [a tutorial for it](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/update-and-fixedupdate).

It's simply used for frame-independent updates in your game.